# Partially random elements in batch after Dataset.shuffle()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using tf.data.Dataset and tf.keras in TF2.1 to train on a dataset. But I saw strange behavior that the resulting batches do not show fully random as I expected. I mean, I usually see elements from only 2 classes in one batch even my dataset has 4 classes. My code is as follows:

```
def process_train_sample(file_path):
  sp = tf.strings.regex_replace(file_path, train_data_dir, '')
  cls = tf.math.argmax(tf.cast(tf.math.equal(tf.strings.split(sp, os.path.sep)[0],['A','B','C','D']), tf.int64))

  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)  # RGB
  img = tf.image.resize(img, (224, 224))
  img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)
  img = img - np.array([123.68, 116.779, 103.939])
  img = img / 255.0
  cls = tf.expand_dims(cls, 0)
  return img, cls

train_data_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(train_data_dir, '**', '*.jpg'), recursive=True)
train_data_list = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_data_list)
train_ds = train_data_list.map(process_train_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(10000)
train_ds = train_ds.batch(batch_size)

for img,  cls in train_ds.take(10):
  print('img: ', img.numpy().shape,  'cls: ', cls.numpy())

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',  
      optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9),
      metrics=['categorical_accuracy', 'categorical_crossentropy'])
model.fit(train_ds, epochs=50)
```

When I'm training on a dataset with 4 classes - A,B,C,D, I found the training accuracy does not increase stably, instead, it fluctuates up and down. Then I checked my data input pipeline by showing labels batch by batch as in the for-loop and found that each batch contains only elements from 2 classes, instead of 4. It seems the dataset is not shuffled as I expected which may cause the accuracy not to increase steadily. But I don't see what's wrong in my code.

Comment: How many images do you have? `>10 000`? You could probably then `random.shuffle(train_data_list)` before converting it into a `tf.data.Dataset` .

Comment: @FrederikBode The dataset is around 30,000. I think the buffer size is not an issue here because I tried larger buffer size but didn't get better results. And I actually tried using random.shuffle on train_data_list as you suggested. For sure it will get better, but if the dataset.shuffle does not work well, the resulting batches will still be kind of fixed with respect to the once-shuffled train_data_list.

Comment: @FrederikBode Seems the results may be different for different running. Sometimes I can get quite random representation in batches. If I set larger buffer size, It's more likely to get better randomness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `.shuffle(10 000)`, the `10 000` is the buffer size, which means it will sample from the first 10 000 images. As you have ~30 000 images, this results in images only from the first and second classes in the first batches batches. As you continue training, you will start to sample from class (1,2,3), then only (2,3), then (2,3,4), then (3,4), then (3,4,1), then (4,1), then (4,1,2), then (1,2), then (1,2,3), and so on.  Try setting shuffle buffer size to 30 000 if you have the memory, or if you don't, first shuffle your list of paths, and then use a large batch size.